# How to assign a string value in a list to a variable over multiple lines

Tags: linux, bash, variables

I have a text file containing a list of all switches in LAN (switch_list.txt), containing the switch names in the first column, and their IP addresses in the second column.
Like this:

SW01    10.10.1.21

SW02    10.10.1.22

SW03    10.10.1.23

...and so on.

What I'm trying to achieve, is to write a script which reads the IP address of the first switch, connects to this IP address, executes a command on the switch, and writes the output to switch_ID.txt.
Then it should skip to the second line, execute the same thing, and so on.
Here's what I tried:

```
while read -r sw ip; do

    ssh ro@$ip show powersupply | grep Internal >> /usr/local/nagios/libexec/switch/$sw.txt

done < switch_list.txt
```

But it only executes the "show powersupply" command on the first switch, and then stops, instead of skipping to the next switch ID/IP in switch_list.txt.
So it writes the output correctly to /usr/local/nagios/libexec/switch/SW01.txt, but then stops.
However, if I replace the "**ssh ro@$ip...**" command with **echo "$sw has the IP address $ip"**, it goes through switch_list.txt, and the output shows every switch in the list, with their IP addresses:

SW01 has the IP address 10.10.1.21

SW02 has the IP address 10.10.2.22

and so on.
My question is, why "**ssh ro@$ip**" connects only to the first switch, and then stops.
What am I doing wrong?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107800/using-while-loop-to-ssh-to-multiple-servers

Comment: Thanks a lot Nic3500, ssh -n did the job.